# Mongo query with $geoWithin and $near together

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

My use case is I want to get all records within a city and nearby some location should come first. 
Lets say I have following records:

```
{"name" : "A", "location" : {"point" : [latlngs1]}}, //LatLng1 is in cityA
{"name" : "B", "location" : {"point" : [latlngs2]}}, //LatLng2 is in cityB
{"name" : "C", "location" : {"point" : [latlngs3]}}, //LatLng3 is in cityA
{"name" : "D", "location" : {"point" : [latlngs4]}}  //LatLng4 is in cityA
```

I wished to get all records within CityA with nearby latlng5.

Say distance bw location points

```
[latlng5, latlng1] --> 10 unit
[latlng5, latlng3] --> 5 unit
[latlng5, latlng4] --> 8 unit
```

So Result should be like this:

```
{"name" : "C"},
{"name" : "D"},
{"name" : "A"}
```

With my research I found that `$geoWithin` is best to apply bounded query, so I can find records within a city using $geoWithin.

> db.TEST.aggregate( [ { $match: {"location.point" : {$geoWithin: {$box:
>   [[northEastLngLat],[SouthWestLngLat] ] } } }, {$project:
>   {name: 1}}]).pretty();

This brings records: A,C and D
Now for nearby places first I found `$geoNear` would fit here.
So Query is like:

> b.TEST.aggregate([ {"$geoNear" : {near: [latlng5], distanceField:
>   "distance", spherical: true}}, {$match: {"location.point" :
>   {$geoWithin: {$box: [[northEastLngLat],[SouthWestLngLat] ]}}},
>   {$project: {name: 1}}]).pretty();

But this produces no output. I tried changing latlngs for $near sometimes for few cases it produce 1 result and for other 0 results.

What is wrong in my query. Please help.
Thank You

Answer (score 1):

You should try this it will fetch all records within 10 km

```
 db.city.find({ 
   location :{
     $near : {
  $geometry : {   
     index : "Point" ,
     coordinates : [19.1, 72.89]
    },
 $maxDistance : 10000
}
 }
     })
```

It will return all records and make sure you have index on location